# Formatting curl return data

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, curl

Hello I am getting a really long string from my curl function that I would like to format into an array. So far I have made it into an array of strings but its not exactly what I want. I want it to be formatted to an array of keys and values.

My PHP:

```
     <?php
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';
    $postcode = $_POST['postcode'];
    $housenumber = $_POST['housenumber'];
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => "https://api-sandbox.postnl.nl/shipment/v2_1/locations/nearest?CountryCode=NL&PostalCode=4301AC",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "apikey: ozxpdJGY0wu4Li64ovzrX1G1Hs5CjRiZ",
            "cache-control: no-cache",
            "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "postman-token: 49b70ffc-7268-1b3a-9646-9002a290f7fe"
        ),
    ));
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    if ($err) {
        echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
    } else {
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
    ?>
```

My Javascript:

```
function getPickUp(){
    var array=[];
    var postcode = document.getElementById('postcode').value;
    var housenumber = document.getElementById('housenumber').value;
        $.ajax({
            url: "PostNLGetPickUp.php",
            data: {postcode: postcode, housenumber:housenumber},
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(output) {
;
                x = (output.toString().slice(2,-2));
                x=x + '';
                x= x.substring(42);
                x= x.split('},{');
                for(var i=0; i< x.length ; i++)
                {
                    x[i]= x[i].replace('"','');
                    x[i]= x[i].replace('"','');
                    array.push([x[i]]);
                }
                console.log(array);
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('Something went wrong');
            }
        });


}
```

The data that is returned by the curl:

```
{
"GetLocationsResult": {
    "ResponseLocation": [
        {
            "Address": {
                "City": "Steenwijk",
                "Countrycode": "NL",
                "HouseNr": 2,
                "Remark": "Dit is een Business Point. Post en pakketten die u op werkdagen vóór de lichtingstijd afgeeft, bezorgen we binnen Nederland de volgende dag. Pakketten die u op zaterdag voor 16:00 uur afgeeft worden maandag bezorgd.",
                "Street": "Koematen",
                "Zipcode": "8331TK"
            },
            "DeliveryOptions": {
                "string": [
                    "DO",
                    "PG",
                    "PGE",
                    "UL",
                    "RETA"
                ]
            },
            "Distance": 408,
            "Latitude": 52.7762318034735,
            "LocationCode": 172743,
            "Longitude": 6.09661444589443,
            "Name": "Formido",
            "OpeningHours": {
                "Friday": {
                    "string": "08:00-21:00"
                },
                "Monday": {
                    "string": "08:00-21:00"
                },
                "Saturday": {
                    "string": "08:00-18:00"
                },
                "Thursday": {
                    "string": "08:00-21:00"
                },
                "Tuesday": {
                    "string": "08:00-21:00"
                },
                "Wednesday": {
                    "string": "08:00-21:00"
                }
            },
            "PartnerName": "PostNL",
            "PhoneNumber": "0521-512293",
            "RetailNetworkID": "PNPNL-01",
            "Saleschannel": "BUPO RET",
            "TerminalType": "NRS"
        },
        {
            "Address": {
                "City": "Steenwijk",
                "Countrycode": "NL",
                "HouseNr": 4,
                "Remark": "Dit is een Pakketpunt. Pakketten die u op werkdagen vóór lichtingstijd afgeeft, bezorgen we binnen Nederland de volgende dag.",
                "Street": "Broekslagen",
                "Zipcode": "8331TJ"
            },
            "DeliveryOptions": {
                "string": [
                    "DO",
                    "PG"
                ]
            },
            "Distance": 515,
            "Latitude": 52.779139711098,
            "LocationCode": 172016,
            "Longitude": 6.09575747888744,
            "Name": "Karwei",
            "OpeningHours": {
                "Friday": {
                    "string": "09:00-21:00"
                },
                "Monday": {
                    "string": "09:00-21:00"
                },
                "Saturday": {
                    "string": "09:00-18:00"
                },
                "Thursday": {
                    "string": "09:00-21:00"
                },
                "Tuesday": {
                    "string": "09:00-21:00"
                },
                "Wednesday": {
                    "string": "09:00-21:00"
                }
            },
            "PartnerName": "PostNL",
            "PhoneNumber": "0521-517393",
            "RetailNetworkID": "PNPNL-01"
        }]}}
```

This is what I managed to make it look like

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWcJJ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any reason you can't call `JSON.parse(data)` from your Javascript? This will convert the string to an object of JSON.

You can then access the location array from inside that object

```
const parsedJSON = JSON.parse(output);
console.log(parsedJSON.GetLocationsResult.ResponseLocation);
```

This will log out the addresses which I think you are trying to get?

Answer (score 0):

If in your javascript you receive the JSON string, you can simply use [JSON.parse() function](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp) like this.

```
x = JSON.parse(output);
```